# If treadmill is accelerating and one is running on it, does he exert less force than if he was accelerating at the same rate while running on ground?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, friction, free-body-diagram

Imagine there is a man running on an treadmill and it is accelerating. If he were to accelerate at the same rate on normal ground, would it require a greater force from him? Discounting air resistance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "accelerate at the same speed" as acceleration and speed are different?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume so. Because the man is not pushing off the ground, the ground is already moving. He only has to move his legs with the motion.

Answer (score 0):

If the man was running on the ground and accelerating relative to the ground the whole of his body needs to accelerate.
If the man is running on a treadmill then the only parts of his body which need to accelerate, as he strides to keep up with the treadmill, are his legs whose mass is less than the whole of his body so smaller forces are involved when on the treadmill.